# DisplayAttribute ResourceType Can't Found Resource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want use resource for showing name in different language.
in below code have error:

```
public class ChangePassword
{
    [Display(Name = "CurrentPassword", ResourceType = typeof(SheardLocalization))]
    public string CurrentPassword { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "NewPassword", ResourceType = typeof(SheardLocalization))]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
}
```

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed. Type 'CyengTeam.App.Models.SheardLocalization' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name 'CurrentPassword'.

in view(.cshtml) i can feath resource by using `@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SheardLocalization> localization;` and don't have any problem. but in class have error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[Required (ErrorMessageResourceName="SomeText", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources.Resource))]
```

The problem occurs in **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** attributes. DisplayAttribute checks the Type.IsVisible property while ValidationAttribute(RequiredAttribute inherit from them) will not. So you need to change your resource class and properties to the public to make it work.
You can read more [Here](https://holyhoehle.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/making-global-resources-public/)

Comment: I maked resources  access modifier public.and  add Required atterbure. but problem not solved

Comment: @alirezasejdei have you tried using ErrorMessageResourceName instead of Name?

Comment: @alirezasejdei you shouldn't use  [Display(Name)] attribute anymore if you use Required  attr